# Spring Security + Angular 2 + SockJS

Tags: spring, angular, spring-security, sockjs

sorry for my bad language at first. I am a student from Germany und new in programming.

I have implemented a little websocket server with Spring Boot and secured it with Spring Security using Basic Auth. Angular 2 is used in the Front End. I have implemented the following solution to connect to the websocket.

> ```
>  * Connects to a websocket server.
>  * @param  {string} url     The url of the WS Server
>  * @param  {string} channel The channel to subscribe
>  * @return {boolean} connection status
>  */
> public connect(url: string, channel: string): boolean {
>     console.group('WebSocketService: Welcome to the connect function.');
>     console.log('Connects to', url);
>     console.log('Channel is', channel);
>     let _self = this;
>     let socket = new SockJS(url);
> ```

```
    _self.wsClient = Stomp.over(socket);

    _self.wsClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
        _self.setConnected(true);
        console.log('Connected: ', frame);
        _self.wsClient.subscribe(channel, function(greeting) {
            console.log(greeting);
            _self.subjects[channel].next(greeting);
        });
    });
    console.groupEnd();
    return true;
}
```

Calling this function let the browser open an input for username and password.
Now i can connect and disconnect from the Server with no need to enter the username / password again.

How can i replace this browser input window with using login information in the code?

I tried to do this by a single Post request like:

> ```
> private test2(){
>   let username : string = 'admin';
>   let password : string = 'pass';
>   let headers = new Headers();
>   headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
>   headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
>   console.log('Test beginnt');
>   return this._http.get('http://localhost:8080/gs-guide-websocket', {headers: headers}).map(res=> console.log(res))
> }
> ```
>
> Blockquote

But this gives me only an http 200 response and did not open a session or something.

I have tried to put the login information in the original request also.

> _self.wsClient.connect('admin','pass', function(frame) { ...}

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't work with SockJS. But I have implemented some small mechanism for pure WebSocket. Maybe it will be helpful

First of all, OAUTH configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@EnableResourceServer
public class OAuth2Configuration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OAuth2Configuration.class);
    private UsersService service = new UsersService();

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;


    @Override
    public void configure( AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {

        authenticationManager.userDetailsService(this.userDetailsService);
        endpoints.authenticationManager((Authentication authentication) ->  authenticationManager.getOrBuild().authenticate(authentication));
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient("application_name")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token")
                .scopes("write", "read", "trust")
                .secret("secret").accessTokenValiditySeconds(24 * 60 * 60);
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return (username) -> {
            return service.getByName(username).map(account -> new User(account.getName(), account.getPassword(), account.getAuthorities())).orElseThrow(
                    () -> new RuntimeException("User not found")
            );
        };
    }
}
```

second, angular2 authorization:

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append("Authorization", "Basic appname:secret");
this.http.post("localhost:8080/oauth_endpoint?grant_type=password&scope=trust&username=" + login + "&password=" + password , "", { headers: headers })
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .subscribe(response => {
          this.accessToken = response.access_token; //will be used for socket
        }
    );
```

third socket configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class SocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(socketHandler(), "/websocket").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }

    @Bean
    public SocketHandler socketHandler() {
        return new SocketHandler();
    }
}

public class SocketHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {

    @Autowired
    private CheckTokenEndpoint checkTokenEndpoint;

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SocketHandler.class);


    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) {
        logger.info("New peer connected: " + session.getId());
    }

    public void handleMessage(WebSocketSession session, WebSocketMessage<?> message) throws Exception {
        logger.debug("Peer is trying to authenticate");
        String token = message.getPayload().toString();
        try {
            checkTokenEndpoint.checkToken(token);
            logger.info("New peer authenticated. ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.warn("Peer unauthenticated!");
            session.close(); //closing connection when provided token doesn't match
        }
    }
}
```

and last, establishing connection via angular2:

```
let ws = new WebSocket("localhost:8080/websocket", []);
ws.onopen = (event: Event) => {
      this.send(
          ws.send()

      });
```

This code may not work if you just copy/paste. I had several other cases to deal with (ie my websocket is reestablishing connection). Because they are out of the question scope, I removed them manually while placing code here.

Comment: This is basically what I've been searching for. Could you please elaborate on the `CheckTokenEndpoint`? Is it enough to send the token in the Authorization header, and will it be picked up by Spring Security automatically?